# Is it OK to have optional parameters in DTOs?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, dto

I am bit confused here. I have a scenario where only certain properties of my DTO would be valid depending on the option chosen. So, I came up below design.

```
[DataContract]
class MyDTO
{
    [DataMember]
    public BaseData CommonData { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public Options AvailableOptions { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public Option1Data Data1 { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public Option2Data Data2 { get; set; }
}
[DataContract]
public class BaseData
{
    [DataMember]
    public int BaseVar1 { get; set; }        
}

[DataContract]
public enum Options
{
    [EnumMember]
    Option1,
    [EnumMember]
    Option2
}

[DataContract]
public class Option1Data
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Option1Var1 { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class Option2Data
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Option2Var1 { get; set; }
}
```

But clearly `MyDTO` class violates OCP principle. When ever, a new option is added in `Options` enum, I need to change `MyDTO` to add one more property to retrieve data for that option.

Is it OK to change `MyDTO` in this case or Do you have a better design?

Answer (score 0):

How about inheritance?

```
[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(Option1))]
[KnownType(typeof(Option2))]
public abstract class BaseData
{
    [DataMember]
    public int BaseVar1 { get; set; }        
}

[DataContract]
public class Option1 : BaseData
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Option1Var1 { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class Option2 : BaseData
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Option2Var1 { get; set; }
}
```

You could also add an `enum` for convenient `switch` etc usage, but it wouldn't need to be a `[DataMember]`, as it would actually be redundant information:

```
public enum Options
{
    Option1,
    Option2
}

[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(Option1))]
[KnownType(typeof(Option2))]
public abstract class BaseData
{
    [DataMember]
    public int BaseVar1 { get; set; }        
    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public abstract Options Option {get;}
}

[DataContract]
public class Option1 : BaseData
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Option1Var1 { get; set; }
    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public override Options Option {get { return Options.Option1; } }
}

[DataContract]
public class Option2 : BaseData
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Option2Var1 { get; set; }
    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public override Options Option {get { return Options.Option2; } }
}
```

Comment: As I said I am bit confused. In general it is recommended to favour composition over inheritance to avoid tight coupling with base class (I guess, if you add a new property in BaseData, it will automatically be inherited in all its derived types which may not be required for certain derived types). So, I used composition for BaseData in MyDTO class.

Comment: @Imran then frankly, use your existing code - but you might as well remove the enum - it adds nothing and is redundant. The callers can just *check which data is available* (by checking for `null` etc).

Comment: I am not satisfied with my existing code :). I agree that enum is redundant. I have added it for convenience so as to hit the exact property depending on the option. But, I guess there is one advantage (really?) with my existing code is that I don't need to downcast BaseData to either Option1 or Option2 depending on abstract Option method.

Comment: @Imran meh; not much difference between a cast and a member-access, in real terms

Comment: Does a DTO need to be OCP compliant? Surely mutability is inherent in its function?